# get a substring from a file shell script

Tags: linux, shell, grep

I need a little help with this shell script. I have a variable, represents a IP/TCP header. I need filter a traffic capture by the header selected.

```
> var=ttl 128
> 
> tcpdump -Xvv -n -i eth0 -c 300 > capture.txt 2>/dev/null
> 
> grep -i "$var" capture.txt > resultGrep.txt
```

The result of the tcpdump command is some like this

```
15:29:18.164566 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 1, id 2394, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 125)
    10.0.0.155.58363 > 239.255.255.254.1900: UDP, length 97
    0x0000:  4600 0024 0000 0000 0102 3ad3 0a00 0000  F..$......:.....
    0x0010:  e000 0001 9404 0000 1101 ebfe 0000 0000  ................
    0x0020:  0300 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000       ..............
15:29:18.164566 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 128, id 2394, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 125)
    10.0.0.131.58363 > 239.255.255.250.1900: UDP, length 97
    0x0000:  4600 0024 0000 0000 0102 3ad3 0a00 0000  F..$......:.....
    0x0010:  e000 0001 9404 0000 1101 ebfe 0000 0000  ................
    0x0020:  0300 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000       ..............
```

I need have ip address source and ip address destination, in the example the output result must be

***10.0.0.131.58363 > 239.255.255.250.1900***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing this directly in a `Unix pipe` over `tcpdump` :

```
tcpdump -Xvv -n -i eth0 -c 300 |
grep -oP "\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}.\d{1,5}\s+>\s+\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}.\d{1,5}"
```

This is rock solid ;)

Comment: That's great sputnick, but i need filter over ttl 128 before. You understand me?

Answer (score 0):

well my understanding of the question is, you want to extract things from your `resultGrep.txt`, not `capture.txt`

then:

```
grep -oP '[\d\.]*\s*>\s*[\d\.]*' resultGrep.txt
```

see test:

```
kent$  echo "15:29:18.164566 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 1, id 2394, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 125)
dquote>     10.0.0.131.58363 > 239.255.255.250.1900: UDP, length 97
dquote>     0x0000:  4600 0024 0000 0000 0102 3ad3 0a00 0000  F..$......:.....
dquote>     0x0010:  e000 0001 9404 0000 1101 ebfe 0000 0000  ................
dquote>     0x0020:  0300 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000       .............."|grep  -oP '[\d\.]*\s*>\s*[\d\.]*'
10.0.0.131.58363 > 239.255.255.250.1900
```