# Get a substring from a file shell script

Tags: linux, shell, grep

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [i need get a substring from a file shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14325857/i-need-get-a-substring-from-a-file-shell-script)

i need a little help with this shell script. I have a variable, represents a IP/TCP header. I need filter a traffic capture by the header selected.

```
> var=ttl 128 (only TTL=128)
> 
> tcpdump -Xvv -n -i eth0 -c 300 > capture.txt 2>/dev/null
>
```

I'm trying using grep command, but only have the line with ttl 128, don't the ip source and destination

```
> grep -i "$var" capture.txt > resultGrep.txt
```

The result of the tcpdump command is some like this

```
15:29:18.164566 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 1, id 2394, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 125)
    10.0.0.155.58363 > 239.255.255.254.1900: UDP, length 97
    0x0000:  4600 0024 0000 0000 0102 3ad3 0a00 0000  F..$......:.....
    0x0010:  e000 0001 9404 0000 1101 ebfe 0000 0000  ................
    0x0020:  0300 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000       ..............
15:29:18.164566 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 128, id 2394, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 125)
    10.0.0.131.58363 > 239.255.255.250.1900: UDP, length 97
    0x0000:  4600 0024 0000 0000 0102 3ad3 0a00 0000  F..$......:.....
    0x0010:  e000 0001 9404 0000 1101 ebfe 0000 0000  ................
    0x0020:  0300 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000       ..............
15:29:18.164566 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 2394, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 125)
    10.0.0.147.58363 > 239.255.255.255.1900: UDP, length 97
    0x0000:  4600 0024 0000 0000 0102 3ad3 0a00 0000  F..$......:.....
    0x0010:  e000 0001 9404 0000 1101 ebfe 0000 0000  ................
    0x0020:  0300 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000       ..............
```

I need have ip address source and ip address destination from packets with ttl 128 header, in the example the output result must be

***10.0.0.131.58363 > 239.255.255.250.1900***

Comment: Will `grep -A1` not work?

Answer (score 0):

If your [`grep`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/grep) supports displaying a context `-A`, you can try

```
grep -A 1 -e 'ttl 128' capture.txt | grep '^    ' | cut -d: -f1
```

The first grep shows all lines with `ttl 128` plus one following line. The second grep filters the lines starting with blanks. The final `cut` selects everything before the first `:`.