# Extract substring from a file shell script

Tags: linux, shell, grep, substring

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [i need get a substring from a file shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14325857/i-need-get-a-substring-from-a-file-shell-script)

I need a little help. I just have a file with contains a capture from command.

> tcpdump -Xvv -n proto \tcp -c 10 > capture.txt 2>/dev/null

The result of the output capture.txt is some like this:

```
15:29:18.164566 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 1, id 2394, offset 0, flags [none], proto TCP (6), length 125)
    10.0.0.243.61908 > 10.0.0.184.80: Flags [S], cksum 0x3d53 (correct), seq 1831050442, win 8192, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
    0x0000:  4600 0024 0000 0000 0102 3ad3 0a00 0000  F..$......:.....
    0x0010:  e000 0001 9404 0000 1101 ebfe 0000 0000  ................
   ..............
15:29:18.164567 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 128, id 2394, offset 0, flags [none], proto TCP (6), length 125)
    10.0.0.184.80 > 10.0.0.243.61908: Flags [S.], cksum 0x135e (correct), seq 2906424792, ack 1831050443, win 5840, options [mss 1460,nop,nop,sackOK,nop,wscale 7], length 0
    0x0000:  4600 0024 0000 0000 0102 3ad3 0a00 0000  F..$......:.....
    0x0010:  e000 0001 9404 0000 1101 ebfe 0000 0000  ................
    0x0020:  0000 0000 0000 0000 2323 2332 2323
    0x0030:  0300 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000       ..............
15:29:18.164569 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 1, id 2394, offset 0, flags [none], proto TCP (6), length 125)
    10.0.0.243.61908 > 10.0.0.184.80: Flags [S], cksum 0x3d53 (correct), seq 1831050442, win 8192, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
    0x0000:  4600 0024 0000 0000 0102 3ad3 0a00 0000  F..$......:.....
    0x0010:  e000 0001 9404 0000 1101 ebfe 0000 0000  ................
    0x0020:  0300 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000       ..............
```

I'm trying to use a grep command : grep -A but I can't make it work.

I need get the destination port locate after the ip destination address.

The output must be:

**80**

**61908**

**80**

Any suggestions?

Comment: What does your `grep` command look like?

Comment: grep -A 1 -e 'proto TCP' capture.txt | grep '^    ' | ... here i'm trying to use cut, but i can't find the correct command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work here.

```
tcpdump -Xvv -i wlan1 -n -nn proto \TCP -c 10 > capture.txt

sed -n 's/.*\.\(.*\): Flags.*/\1/p' capture.txt
443
35673
443
35071
80
```

Comment: I tried, but here's something wrong. This is the output

      22

      62036

      80

      Date

      ], seq 1

      ], seq 1461

      ], seq 3472502811

Answer (score 1):

```
grep -oP '> \d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+' capture.txt | cut -d. -f5
```